# Rewrite rule doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have got this url:

> www.site.ru/page.php?article=anyname

I want to see this url:

> www.site.ru/anyname

My rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteRule /page.php?article=(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it's not working, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?article=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ page.php?article=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. What i mus to read and learn for understand this magic? :)